# t distributions in Excel and R

Tags: r, excel

I want to know `Prob(X<x)` for a given x in a t-distribution.
But I get different values in R and Excel (office 2016).

In R,

```
> pt(-5.9937,27.07)
[1] 1.064476e-06
```

In Excel,

```
=T.DIST(-5.9937,27.07,TRUE)
1.07553E-06
```

When df=27, they give the same value.

Comment: I would say go with R.

Comment: iirc excel does have a gamma distribution, which can be used to formulate the t distribution for real valued df.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Excel truncates your df parameter to an integer value. This makes sense for the most common applications of the t distribution, where df represents the (integer) degrees of freedom for a model, but neglects the fact that the distribution is actually defined for any real (positive) df.

Comment: I should have noticed this from the values!